# Are tags considered an important thing to edit?

Tags: support, tags

Are tags something that should be edited to make them more correct? the basis of this question comes from the fact that tags are used for organisation and searching and so would need to be correct to have a highly efficient system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, yes.  Tags should be as 'right' as possible.  The easier the question is to locate in the future, the better.

Comment: Thanks, just checking to make sure I have the right idea.